# What's the benefit with using generic attributes over adding new fields to an entity table

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, nopcommerce

I'm wondering what the point of using the generic attributes are.
Is it mainly for allowing easy of upgrades in the future, or is there a real performance impact/improvement by using the generic attributes over just adding new columns to the database table.

I have tried both, and can't see any difference.
I also done some googling but can't find anything describing why generic attributes should be used.

If we constantly use generic attributes, that table will get rather large and surely have a performance impact anyway if caching is not utilized by other developers.

```
var ga = cacheManager.Get("BANNER_MANUFACTURER_" + Model.Id, () =>
    {
        var genericAttribute = genericAttributeService.GetAttributesForEntity(Model.Id, "Manufacturer").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "BannerPictureId");
        return genericAttribute;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually generic attribute table is used when you want to store tiny values. There are different reasons why people use it. In case I want to store some values but don't want to create a whole table for that(as adding a table required bit more code customization) in such case people uses generic attribute table.

But there is no performance impact so far.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I noticed all the values in that table have small values like picture ids etc so I felt like modifying the table was the right solution. Because I'm adding about 12 columns to the table I wasn't sure which was the best approach but this clarifies it for me. If I was just adding one or two pictures I would use the attributes :)